# Polynomial equal to analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let p(z) be a polynomial of degree n.  Show $\exists R$ and analytic $f(z)$ such that $p(z)=f(z)^n$ for $|z|>R$

Answer (score 4):

Write
\begin{align}
p(z) &= a_nz^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0 \\
     &= a_nz^n \bigg( 1 + \underbrace{\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n z} + + \frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n z^2} + \cdots  + \frac{a_{0}}{a_n z^n} }_{h(z)} \bigg).
\end{align}
If $|z| > R$, where $R$ is large enough, then $|h(z)| < 1$ (since $h \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$). Hence $1+h(z)$ has a well-defined holomorphic $n$th root, and we can write $p(z) = f(z)^n$, where
$$
f(z) = a_n^{1/n} z\,(1+h(z))^{1/n}
$$
(the choice of value of $a_n^{1/n}$ doesn't matter.)

Comment: do you mean $h \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @YuanGao Oh, sorry, of course.